# Fundamental Solution to 2nd Order ODE

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

I'm currently doing a problem with the fundamental solution for $$-u''+k^2u=f(x) \quad , \quad -\infty < x < \infty$$
I'm wondering if fundamental solutions are supposed to satisfy the homogeneous equation or the above equation? Thanks.

Comment: [Wiki:Fundamental solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution)

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental solution, as mentioned, satisfies $-u''+k^2 u = \delta_{y}(x)$. To the left or to the right of $y$, the fundamental solution satisfies $-u''+k^2u=0$. The fundamental solution needs to be continuous across $y$, and, in order to have the $\delta$ function behavior, there is a discontinuity in the first derivative of the solution with a jump of $-1$ so that $-u''$ pop's out the delta function at $y$.

The only requirements at $\pm\infty$ is that the fundamental solution should be in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Assume $k > 0$. In this case, that means
$$
          u(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}C_1e^{kx}, & -\infty < x < y \\
              C_2e^{-kx}, & y < x < \infty.\end{array}\right.
$$
The constants $C_1$, $C_2$ are chosen so that $u$ is continous at $y$ and so that the derivative of $u$ has a jump of $+1$ as $x$ crosses $x$ from below to above $y$. That is,
$$
                     C_2 e^{-ky} - C_1 e^{ky} = 0 \\
                     -kC_2 e^{-ky}-kC_1 e^{ky} = 1.
$$
Multiplying the first equation by $k$ and adding gives
$$
                             -2kC_1e^{ky} = 1 \implies C_1 = -\frac{1}{2k}e^{-ky}.
$$
Multiplying the first by $k$ and subtracting instead gives
$$
                       2kC_2e^{-ky} = -1 \implies C_2 = -\frac{1}{2k}e^{ky}
$$
Therefore, $u$ can be written as
$$
        u_y(x) = -\frac{1}{2k}e^{-k|x-y|}
$$

Comment: @Winther : I really mean $\delta_{y}(x)$. I've changed that.

Answer (score 1):

Typically a "fundamental solution" or "Green's function" is a function that solves the equation $-u'' + k^2u = \delta(x).$

Comment: And how would you test that the fundamental solution satisfies that equation if it is given to you?

Comment: It would satisfy the homogeneous solution away from the origin, and necessarily blow up approaching the origin... very much like the delta functional.  Id suggest using the Fourier transform in this case to find the fundamental solution.  Take the transform of both sides, solve for ${\hat u}$ and invert, then you can be sure that your Green's function satisfies the equation.